# One user always unsuccessfull in logging into the MFP via DSS

Tags: hp

We use HP M4345 MFP's here with the HP DSS software.  All the users can log into the MFP except for one particular user.  I haven't been able to find out why.  We are leaning towards her active directory account might be goofed.  However I hate to delete the account and recreate it as it will cause a lot of extra work.

Looking for any advice before we have to proceed down that road.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with HP's Digital Sending Software before, but I'd suspect that the troubleshooting necessary would be similar to troubleshooting any LDAP-based authentication integration. (From what I'm reading it looks like it doesn't have any special "hooks" for Active Directory and treats it as an LDAP server...)

I'd throw a sniffer at the traffic between the MFP and the domain controller(s) that it's validating the logon against and see what looks different between the "problem" user and a known-working user. Seeing the traffic on the wire is always a good thing.